# ForkJoinPool - работа на нескольких ядрах

Tags: java, многопоточность

ForkJoinPool общий имеет параллельность "кол-во ядер - 1", соответственно если есть 4 ядра, то из 4 запущенных потоков 1 будет чередоваться с остальными в выполнении на ядре. Но почему если я создаю собственный FJP, и задаю ему параллельность равную 4, то все равно те же 4 потока выполняются на 3 ядрах? Это я проверил так: запустил объемную задачу для каждого из 2 потоков - в каждом из потоков выполнилась за 3.3 сек, запустил задачу для 3 потоков - те же 3.3 сек для каждого потока, запустил задачу для 4 потоков - все, выполнение в каждом заняло 4-5 сек.
Разве JVM резервирует себе аж одно ядро на GC и т д?

Comment: время на инициализацию не принимается в счет.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что он имеет параллельность "кол-во ядер - 1", если дефолтный конструктор выглядит так:

    public ForkJoinPool() {
            this(Math.min(MAX_CAP, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()),
                 defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, false);
        }

Comment: @RomanC, оно действительно не принимается. Отсчет времени начинался конкретно с начала выполнения задачи, а не с начала работы потока и т д

Comment: @ИванГладуш, на основе собственных тестов, из-за вызова .toString(), через который указано что параллельность = 3, также на основании этой темы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494811/why-doesnt-the-common-forkjoinpool-try-to-use-all-cores"

Comment: а вы каким образом разделили задачу? на сколько задач делится большая задача?  учли что оптимально задачу делить надо с поправочным коэффициентом 10..100 ?

Comment: @dSH я ее не делил) я одно и то же задание(вычисление квадратного корня из квадратного корня итерационной переменной несколько миллиардов раз) запускал на 2,3,4 потоках. При 2 или 3 потоках выполнение у каждого из потоков занимало около 3.3 сек. Когда я запустил это на 4 потоках, то у каждого это заняло по 4-5 сек, что означает что эти 4 потока работали на всего лишь 3 ядрах

Answer (score 1):

1. Общий ответ наверное такой - зависит от реализации JVM.
2. При создании своего ForkJoinPool в системе появляются два ForkJoinPool, потому что один системный используется например в StreamAPI. В таком случае планировать загрузку ЦПУ становится намного сложнее. Поэтому для создания еще одного ForkJoinPool нужно иметь конкретное обоснование. Рекомендуется использовать системный
3. Надо еще смотреть каким образом разбилась задача.Т.е. оптимальное соотношение - размер задачи делится на число ядер, а потом еще на поправочный коэффициент 10..100. Иначе либо ядра не будут задействованы, либо большая часть времени пойдет не на задачу, а ее деление ее на подзадачи.
4. Надо осторожно относиться к замерам, измеренным "на коленке". Слишком много подводных камней в этой теме. И конечно нужен код чтоб понять что измерилось, желательно с указанием конкретной JVM и операционной системы, имеющегося "железа".

Но если говорить о тестах "на коленке" то вот что дал запуск теста ForkJoinPool на моей машине:
     [image: Произвольный тест ForkJoinPool]

Прошу не обращать внимание на конкретные числа - просто это время выполнения. Важны относительные показатели. Выигрыш при паралелизме = 4 есть, просто здесь как и во многих других областях жизни соблюдается закон предельной полезности - каждая следующая единица ресурса приносит все меньше пользы. 
Удивило что семерка при параллелизме = 1 лучше оказалась.

Вот нагрузка на процы - т.е. в моем случае нагрузка полная при параллелизме 4: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Параллельность можно измерять на коленке, особенно если задачи большие. А если реализация JVM это OracleJDK и стрим АПИ FJP ничего сейчас не делает, то почему нормально на 4 ядра не происходит нормального распараллеливания ?

Comment: а сколько всег ядер у вас на железе - 4?

Comment: да у меня 4 ядра на железе, без гипертредов

Comment: сообщите остальные параметры сразу - какая ОС, какая версия jvm и по возможноти код - попробую на выходных поэкспериментировать

Comment: по горизонтали параллелизм конечно

Comment: Все это очень здорово, а можете показать загрузку ядер во время работы теста на 4 потоках?

Comment: добавил скриншот нагрузки - у меня полная получилась. При параллизме 3 неполная